# minimize norm $||C-A^TB ||^2$ by taking derivative with respect to vector

Tags: matrix-calculus, nonlinear-optimization, frechet-derivative

Let's try to minimimize a matrix function $f(B)=||C-A^TB ||$ with respect to $B$. Here $C_{k \times 1}$  and $A_{3 \times k}$ and $B_{3 \times 1}$ matrices. One solution presented to me was to take the matrix [norm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) squared:
$$||C-A^TB ||^2= C^T C + A^TBB^{-1}A - 2A^{T}BC$$
and then differentiate by $B$. That's the argument that was presented to me.
$$ 2AA^T B - 2AC   =0 \text{ so that }
B=(AA^T)^{-1}AC $$
How can I make rigorous? Here are some possibilities:

- [matrix derivative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus)
- [directional derivative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative)
- [Fréchet derivative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative)
- [Gâteaux derivative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative)

Comment: You don't say, among $A,B,C$, which is the variable matrix. $B$  ?

Comment: minimize with respect to $B$

Comment: There is a problem with the dimensions of $A$ : as you transpose it, A should be $3 \times K$ (i.e., 3 rows ; K columns) . Is that right ?

Comment: You're simply finding the [least-squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Linear_least-squares) solution of a linear system $$\eqalign{ &A^Tb=c \cr &b=(A^T)^+c }$$ A problem which is covered in exhaustive detail in any number of Linear Algebra texts. If you're seeking clarity and rigor, an optimization approach involving Frechet derivatives is probably not the way to proceed.